# Xcode 4 - When creating an archive it doesn't show in the organiser

Tags: xcode, distribution, archive, provisioning

When I go to "Product" on the menu and then "Archive", it builds successfully. But when I go to Organiser and Archives, nothing shows there.
I find on the disk it has created archive files but they are zero Kb.

I have made sure in my Scheme that the "Reveal Archive in Organiser" is ticked.
I have "Skip Install" set to No in my main project and target.
I have no dependant projects.
I have "Bundle versions strings, short" in my plist set to the same as "Bundle version".
I have created a distribution certificate online and used that as my code signing profile in the build settings.
I have taken out the installation directory in the build settings.
And done many of the other thing people mention in other posts with no luck at all.

This was a new Xcode 4 application so there is no history with version 3.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or at least know how to find why it doesn't show. Maybe a log somewhere that you can dig into?

Thanks

Comment: PS we do use the ZXing library for the app to do barcode scanning but don't have the full project included. Just the libZxingWidget.a file included (its the built library file for IOS device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed.
I never had anything in the "Installation Directory" property on my main target.
I added "/usr/local/lib" to it and now the archive works.